# What happens to print quality if I double the DPI at the same dimensions?

Tags: dpi

I have a photo in 72DPI w70 h50 but the printing company tells me i ned a higher DPI. So what happens with the quality if I double the DPI to 144DPI but keep the size w70 h50?

Comment: What unit of measurement is w70 and h50?  Also what physical size are you trying to print the image? Can't really answer this properly without those details.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what the unit behind h and w are. If H and W are physical units (which i assume they are) then:

Nothing really. Yeah technically you can do better interpolation than your printers Rasterizer (aka. RIP), and preview the result giving you a chance to intervene. But it's still the same thing, interpolation. Its not like the RIP wouldn't do this anyway. If you haven't got the pixels then you haven't got the pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I guess w70 h50 means your photo is 70 millimetrs wide and 50 millimeters high. Rising to 144DPI affects positively if you do the DPI upgrading in the following way:

You have somewhere a sharp original which has much higher DPI than 72, say 300DPI in the same millimeter size 70x50. You totally discard your 72DPI version and resample the 300DPI original to 144DPI, but keep the millimeter size the same.

Of course the DPI doubling is idiotic if you can quadruple it by inserting the 300DPI version.

Obviously you have not that 300DPI original, you have only the 72DPI version. Resampling it to 144DPI and millimeter size 70x50 doesn't recreate the missing data, the result would be as blurry as if you did nothing, but let the printhouse do the reasampling in their printing process.

Sometimes image enlargening software can guess partially the missing data. It can keep sharp edges and thin lines when it resamples the image to bigger pixel dimensions. Subjectively the result can be much better than what's available with resampling in Photoshop.

I have used enlargers many times. In all cases a client had imagined that web images or screenshots are ok for printing, brought them to me in the last minute and there was simply no other possiblity than to attempt enlargening. (Drawings can be redrawn, but photos cannot)

Try Smilla, it's a free enlarger. There are many commercial products, too, for example OnOne Resize, which has been around at least since 1997 under different names. Originally it was Genuine Fractals, but it has been renamed few times due the owner changes.

Search for photo enlarger or image enlarger to see what is available.

An opinion: There are also poor versions which do nothing more clever than ordinary resampling. Smilla and OnOne Resize at least try to guess missing details. See comparison reviews.

ADD:  Just in case your iimage happens to be 70x50 pixels, doubling the DPI boosts the apparent sharpness remarkably. Unfortunately the printed size is halved, it is only about 12 millimeters wide.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to print quality if I double the DPI at the same dimensions?

The quality degrades.

You are asking the application to [interpolate](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm) pixel data and fabricate new pixels based on values from surrounding pixels, then to *guess* as to the values of the new pixels.

Quality will pretty much never *improve* merely by interpolating pixels. However, interpolation can result in a usable image. It all really depends upon the image itself and how well the interpolation operation guesses.

For print production, there's almost *never* a benefit to using a 72ppi image for *anything* unless the physical dimensions can be reduced. You can easily take a 100mm x 100mm 72ppi image and reduce it to a 23mm x 23mm image @ 300ppi. However, if you need the image to remain at 70x50mm.... then you really should find another image.